# Передача параметров фрагменту от активити без создания экземпляра фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, android-intent

Содержимое активити(не MainActivity ) взято из первого фрагмента из SQLite через Intent(с этим проблем нет). В этом в активити есть кнопка, по нажатию которой необходимо брать один из параметров, которые пришли в него через Intent и передавать их второму фрагменту. Оба фрагмента уже созданы через FragmentManager в MainActivity. Через Intent не передать, через newInstance  тоже не выходит, т.к. создаётся фрагмент,который уже итак есть. Собственно сам вопрос - каким образом передать нужные параметры из активити во фрагмент, например, как в моём случае строку?

Comment: например с помощью вот такой штуки https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus или вот такой http://square.github.io/otto/ Только не увлекайтесь этим и используйте, когда реально без этого не обойтись, а то можно такого нагородить

Comment: Спасибо. Это, как я понимаю, стронние разработки. А есть ли стандартные способы это сделать?

Comment: [стандартные способы](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) - фрагментам присваиваем теги. Находим в FragmentManager нужный фрагмент по тегу. В самом фрагменте делаем метод передачи значения. Вызываем у найденного по тегу фрагмента этот метод или реализация интерфейса обратного вызова, в зависимости от решаемых задач.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу тут в общих чертах как это можно сделать.
Создаем интерфейс `SomeInterface` с одним методом, который будет принимать строку, и делаем так, чтобы фрагмент реализовывал этот интерфейс.
Когда вам нужно передать данные из активити во фрагмент, берете текущий фрагмент(его можно сохранить в переменную, но лучше доставать из `fragmentManager` по тэгу) и проверяете, реализует ли фрагмент `SomeInterface`, если да, то можно смело кастовать и вызывать нужный метод.